# Process f:viewParam only on page load

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, viewparams

I'm using an `<f:viewParam>` to pass a parameter as follows.

```
<ui:define name="metaData">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.entity}" converter="#{converter}"/>
    </f:metadata>
</ui:define>
```

Is it possible to process this `<f:viewParam>`, only when the page is loaded/refreshed?

It is just because the converter as specified with the `<f:viewParam>` is costly that converts the value passed through the query-string to a JPA entity. Hence, it involves an expensive database transaction, even when doing **ajaxical** postbacks using components like `<p:commandButton>`, `<p:commandLink>` which is unnecessary.

So, when for example, a `<p:commandLink>` (**ajaxical**) is clicked, the expensive business service (in the converter) should not be executed. Can this be done?

---

This somehow works (strange enough nevertheless), when the `rendered` attribute is evaluated against `facesContext.postback` like `rendered="#{not facesContext.postback}"` but the attribute `rendered` is [not documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/f/viewParam.html). Hence, it is unreliable.

Comment: Thanks @Tiny for this question, which describes exactly the situation I encountered as described here [p:dataTable how prevent f:viewParam being invoked on 1st rowEdit then “tick save” using JSF at XHTML level (not in Java in backing bean)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408949/jsf-pdatatable-how-prevent-fviewparam-being-invoked-on-1st-rowedit-then-tick)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a custom tag extending `<f:viewParam>` wherein you store the submitted value as an instance variable which isn't stored in JSF view state instead of in the JSF view state as the `<f:viewParam>` by default does. By end of request, all UI component instances are destroyed. They are recreated in beginning of the request. When submitted value is `null`, then it won't call the converter nor the model setter. This all is elaborated in [Arjan Tijms' blog](http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2011/07/stateless-vs-stateful-jsf-view.html).

[OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) offers already since version 1.0 a ready to use solution in flavor of [`<o:viewParam>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/viewParam), see also [my own blog](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2012/03/stateless-view-parameter.html) on that. Based on your question history, you're already using OmniFaces, so all you basically need to do is to replace `f:` by `o:`.

```
<ui:define name="metaData">
    <f:metadata>
        <o:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.entity}" converter="#{converter}"/>
    </f:metadata>
</ui:define>
```

This won't call the model setter (nor the converter) during postbacks on the same view.

---

> *This somehow works (strange enough nevertheless), when the rendered attribute is evaluated against facesContext.postback like rendered="#{not facesContext.postback}" but the attribute rendered is not documented. Hence, it is unreliable.*

That's because the [`<f:viewParam>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewParameter.html) is in essence an [`UIInput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) component (else it wouldn't be able to perform conversion, validation, model-update and all that stuff like usual input components) which is thus just an [`UIComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html) supporting a [`rendered`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#isRendered%28%29) attribute. This is however not explicitly documented as it actually doesn't render anything to the HTML output (that's also why it's a `f:xxx`, not a `h:xxx`). But with this attribute you can actually control the behavior during postback as this attribute is [also](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.faces/javax.faces-api/2.2/javax/faces/component/UIInput.java#UIInput.processDecodes%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) evaluated in [`processDecodes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#processDecodes%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) method which is invoked during apply request values phase.

Comment: The referenced link for [Arjan Tijms' blog.](http://jdevelopment.nl/stateless-stateful-jsf-view-parameters/) seems to be broken now.