# p:dataTable how prevent f:viewParam being invoked on 1st rowEdit then “tick save” using JSF at XHTML level (not in Java in backing bean)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets, jsf-2.3

*EDIT: 2017-04-28 The exact same problem (different circumstances/application) is described here: [Process f:viewParam only on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23903351/process-fviewparam-only-on-page-load)*

---

Primefaces 6.1.RC2

JSF Mojarra 2.3.0

---

I already have a Java backing-bean based workaround (explained below) for the problem the following behaviour of `p:dataTable` causes, but I am not very happy with that workaround, and I would like to understand the behavior of `p:dataTable` row editing better and if possible I would like to find a purely XHTML-level solution to my problem. (BTW I am otherwise very experienced with `p:dataTable`, which I have used for some very complex applications for some years.)

It is not about an error or bug in `p:dataTable`, but the way it behaves during row editing causes me a problem in one situation.

The following code examples are completely simplified and adapted for this forum.

I have an entity Element, which has a relationship `List<Link> getLinks()`, where Link is also an entity.

Element has an editor `edit.xhtml`.

The aim is to have an composite component `links_editor.xhtml` that can be embedded in the `edit.xhtml`.

There is a CDI-compliant `@ViewScoped @Named` backing bean `Manager`.

The edit.xhtml relies on an `f:viewParam` to load an Element for editing:

```
<f:view>
    <f:metadata>
       <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{manager.id}"/>
    </f:metadata>
</f:view>
```

Where in the backing bean `Manager`:

```
public void setId(Long id) {
    if (id != null) {
      //load an Element from database for editing by id
```

And in the `links_editor.xhtml`:

```
<cc:implementation>
    <div id="#{cc.clientId}">

                <p:growl id="testgrowl"/>

                <p:dataTable
                    id="links_table"
                    editable="true"                    
                    var="link"
                    value="#{cc.attrs.element.links}"
                    >   

                    <p:ajax 
                        event="rowEdit" 
                        listener="#{cc.attrs.manager.onLinkRowEdit}"
                        update="#{cc.clientId}:testgrowl"
                        />

                    <p:column headerText="Link title">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText value="#{link.name}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <p:inputText id="name" value="#{link.name}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>                        
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Link URL">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText value="#{link.urlAsString}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <p:inputText id="url" value="#{link.urlAsString}"/>
                                <p:message 
                                    for="url" 
                                    display="icon"                                        
                                    />
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>                        
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:rowEditor />
                    </p:column>                    
                </p:dataTable>
```

The row edit listener:

```
public void onLinkRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
    Link link = (Link) event.getObject();
    try {
        checkLink(link); //throws if URL string malformed         
        JsfUtil.addInfoMessage("DEBUG: Link: "+link);
    } catch (LocalUpdateException ex) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

(where `JsfUtil` obviously just leverages `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(...)`)

**The issue/concern:**

If I edit a Link row in the `p:dataTable` **a first time** and then use the "tick save" the `onLinkRowEdit` listener is invoked, but the diagnostics show that the value appear not to have changed. The reason is that this `f:viewParam` is invoked:

```
       <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{manager.id}"/>
```

This (via routes not shown in detail) loads the `Element` entity again from database via `setId(Long id)`, so that in the composite component `edit_links.xthml` this essentially resets `#{cc.attrs.element.links}`, so any changes are discarded.

The interesting thing is that if (without reloading the entire @ViewScoped page) one edits the same `p:dataTable` row **a second time** that `f:viewParam` is NOT invoked, and thereafter it works as desired.

A workaround (rather hacky) is to "block" any attempt to reload the Element by id within the view scope backing bean `Manager`:

```
public void setId(Long id) {

   //HACK/WORKAROUND: prevent reload of Element by id
   if (Objects.equals(id, this.id)) {
       return;
   }

    if (id != null) {
      //load an Element from database for editing by id
```

To be clear, I am aware of the usual strategies for using @PostConstruct and/or lazy database fetching in getters of frequently accessed info under JSF in backing beans. And I don't want to abandon here the `f:viewParam` approach entirely (and it works well for other situations the same Manager bean is also used for).

My interest is specifically about Primefaces `p:dataTable`:

Q1: Why does `p:dataTable` need to call the `f:viewParam` during the 1st row edit then "tick save", when the row information (in this cases `element.links`) is clearly already available ?

Q2: Why does `p:dataTable` NOT need to call the `f:viewParam` during the 2nd row edit then "tick save" ?

Q3: Is there a JSF XHTML-based way of preventing `p:dataTable` from calling the `f:viewParam` at all during a rowEdit then "tick save" (including the 1st go) ?

---

**UPDATE: 2017-04-21: There is now a mini test web app for NetBeans 8.2** demonstrating the problem at:

https://github.com/webelcomau/Webel_PrimeFaces_test_p50445_dataTable_fviewParam

Please just [download the master ZIP-archive](https://github.com/webelcomau/Webel_PrimeFaces_test_p50445_dataTable_fviewParam/archive/master.zip), unzip it, and open it in NetBeans IDE 8.2. You don't need to Git-clone the project. Make sure you have Glassfish-4.1.1 set as the server for the project.

Both the README there and the web app test page itself give precise steps for reproducing the problem (or the behavior that concerns me).

I have invested some effort in analysing this because I use `p:dataTable` "embedded" in edit forms together with `f:viewParam` a lot, and I want to understand this matter better, even if it is not an actual problem with `p:dataTable`.

Comment: My Q's: Does the same happen with PF 6.0 and/or JSF 2.2? How do you know the `p:datatable` calls the viewparam and not something the JSF impl does (in other words, who is the culprit) Does the same happen when not using a custom component? Are there fundamental differences in what is posted from the client to the server? And do you have an [mcve] so I can try to reproduce

Comment: @Kukeltje Good questions. I know same happened with PF6.0 and JSF 2.3.0-m07 (would need test case for earlier since main/real web app not compatible with earlier JSF version). I know that performing the first (only) p:dataTable rowEdit then "tick save" _triggers_ the the f:viewParam to be invoked because I can see it logged in setId(Long); I can try in NetBeans debugger might show more of the sequence (i.e. something JSF impl does). Will prepare a minimal example with a comparison of within CC vs outside in standalone h:form (but might be over this weekend, probably not tonight Sydney time).

Comment: Thanks, no problem... And it is a looooooong wekend in Utrecht/Amsterdam (monday is a holiday)

Comment: @Kukeltje [Mini test web app for NetBeans 8.2 on GitHub clearly demonstrating the issue/concern/behaviour](https://github.com/webelcomau/Webel_PrimeFaces_test_p50445_dataTable_fviewParam), grateful for any feedback.

Comment: The exact same problem (different circumstances/application) is described here: [Process f:viewParam only on page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23903351/process-fviewparam-only-on-page-load)